# Does inheritance increase coupling?

Tags: java, c++, oop

I am fairly new to object oriented programming techniques and as i understand, coupling is the biggest obstacle in creating maintainable, reusable code.

When we make several child classes inherit from a base class, don't the child classes become dependent on the base class? What if i have to remove the base class at a later point in time. Wouldn't this break the code in the child classes?

Comment: Standard subtype OOP *relies on* following [the general idea of] LSP. So yes, changing the parent (such that the child cannot hold to it's previously stated contracts) will break the child class. However this is an odd (but I cannot argue for it being incorrect) usage of 'coupling'. Maybe that just means that coupling is *assumed / implied by* in implementation subtype relations..

Comment: It would surely break the code in the child classes. One way to avoid this is to use an interface rather than using a superclass. But why would you remove such an important superclass?

Comment: But interfaces only allow data members and not member functions. So wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose of inheritance?

Comment: @JobinJose FWIW, I very rarely use inheritance (but use interfaces and DI *a lot*), and with a few exceptions of tree-like libraries (such as UI controls, for instance) find that it is an overused construct. I would even go so far to argue that in Java it is often used as a bandage over the desire to re-use code without other merit. (I can't speak of C++ usage, but it's a different language.)

Comment: That is also true... So I will quote @user2864740 However this is an odd usage but I can't argue it for being incorrect. But why will you remove a superclass that is so important that it is inherited by so many child classes?

Comment: @Nabeel Lets suppose our child class requires to use three or four functions of some base class. But its main purpose does not lie in those inherited methods but it only uses those methods to achieve a less important/relevant purpose. Now what if i need to reuse this child class in another program. Wouldn't i need to carry the base class along with the child to every new program where i want to reuse the child class? To make things worse, imagine there are more than one such base classes from which the child class inherits(multiple inheritance)

Comment: @JobinJose if the inherited functions are less important will it not be better to create those functions again in the child class?

Comment: Or to add the access modifier "public" in the super class and access those functions by instantiating the super class in the child class?

Comment: @Nabeel I thought of that initially. But inheritance seems to be a big deal in creating a good design. That's why i asked the question here

Comment: Recreating functions in child class seems to be the best option in such cases.  i think the second method you suggested would still break the code in the same way as regular inheritance. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @JobinJose I disagree with "inheritance seems to be a big deal in creating a good design" are you saying that not using inheritance makes for a bad design? What do you think about C, it has no object orientation, but is arguably the **lingua franca** of programming....

Comment: Welcome anytime @JobinJose, it was nice having a discussion with you.

Comment: Anything where the actual name of a class appears in the source code of another class increases coupling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This is referred to as [*Subclass Coupling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#Object-oriented_programming):

> Describes the relationship between a child and its parent.

Like all coupling, affecting one unit may affect the units that depend on it.

In this case, removing the parent class would affect *all* it's child classes, as a compiler error would occur on removal of the supertype.

This means the child classes are coupled to the supertype.

Comment: If there is such a disadvantage with inheritance, why is it so overhyped in the OOP world? Apparently, every article on OOP does mention inheritance somewhere and as a magical concept to solve many problems. Is code reuse the only advantage of Inheritance?

Comment: @JobinJose It's actually not over-hyped, from what I see. Only some languages allow multiple inheritence, and there are tons of topics on Inheritence vs Composition. It's just a system that helps us achieve what we want. I can see how polymorphism is hyped, but polymorphism can't be applied to everything. It may help if you referenced where you see this "hype"

Comment: @JobinJose inheritance helps to reduce the lines of code needed to be written. Moreover, the stuff you are talking about is hypothetical. What are the odds of having to remove a super important super class from a code after a lot of child classes have be constructed that inherit from it?

Comment: @Nabeel Actually, that's how inheritence can be abused. You should always use the "is-a" or "has-a" concept: `Dog` is-a `Animal`, so `Dog extends Animal`. Using inheritence to minimize code isn't the best way to view it. Think of it of a way to group specific types, allowing you to give each specific type functionality through instance methods, which can be overriden to allow more specific behavior

Comment: @VinceEmigh but that is what I am asking about, what are the odds of the class animal being removed from the program when millions of classes inherit from it?

Comment: @NabeelOmer Removing `Animal` suggests your application no longer needs animals. This means it no longer needs `Dog` or `Cat` either, because they are also `Animal`. Dog is a Animal

Comment: I guess i had a misconception about the use of inheritance. My idea was that whenever you see that two or more classes use the same methods, you just have to place the common methods in a new class and then make the other classes inherit from it. I thought of it as a commandment from the holy book of OOP. Now i understand that its not that important. Thanks a lot for the help guys :)

Comment: @JobinJose that is absolutely true, it has been 1½ years since I started java and I have used inheritance 2-3 times only. Specially when working with GUI.

Comment: @JobinJose It can actually be extremely useful if used correctly. Like I said, polymorphism can do wonders, and I'd definitely look into it if I were you. Inheritence is at the core of [designing by contracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Personally, I'd say it's pretty holy ;) But don't abuse it! If you want to talk more about this, feel free to [start a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) if you have 20+ rep

Comment: @JobinJose I suggest you learn a little C, you'll get to know what all can be done without OOB. And perhaps in a better way.

Comment: @NabeelOmer C lacks object orientation in all (there are hacks you can do to achieve a generic oo style, but it's not the same), so my guess is that you need a little bonding time with oop :) It can do amazing things

Comment: Actually i have been programming in C from past 3-4 years. I know a little bit of java and i am mainly starting to learn C++. I am getting intrigued by the vast number of new principles and concepts of the OOP part of c++.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I don't think that there is any thing that cannot be done in C and even in C++ every thing is possible, even if you don't use the OOB part. It has been ½ years since I started C\C++ (I don't know which one of them I use, I use `printf()` with `new`!) before that even I thought that OOB was amazing but you get to procedural programming you see that OOB is over rated...

Comment: @NabeelOmer Reflection cannot be performed in C. If you want to continue this convo, please create a chat. This is getting a bit off topic for this question/answer. If you do create a chat, don't forget to tag my name when you send a message so I'll get notified.

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes Vince I would love to continue this conversation but I have only 51 reputation and I cannot create a chat room. But you can create it. You have a lot of reputation... So I suggest you create the chatroom and add me and Jobin Jose...

Answer (score 5):

The relationship between a parent class and its subclasses is known as *subclassing dependency* or *implementation dependecy*. As other types of dependecy, implementation dependecy generates some coupling between two classes. Remember that coupling **must** be minimize among classes in your architecture.

As stated in the book *Design Pattern*, the only way to reduce this kind of coupling is using the following principle:

> Program to an interface, not to an implementation.

Then, if you have to use inheritance, the best way to do it is using *abstract classes* as parent classes and letting subclasses to override only abstract methods.

Using inheritance between concrete classes is also called **white box code reuse**.

> Parent classes often define at least part of their subclasses' physical representation. Because inheritance exposes a subclass to the details of its parent's implementation, it's often said that "*inheritance breaks encapsulation*".

Then, use **black box code reuse**, instead, a.k.a. object compisition, which doesn't break encapsulation and minimize subclassing coupling.