# How does inheritance lead to higher coupling than composition?

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

One major reason for using composition over inheritance is, that inheritance leads to higher coupling. How is that?
As long as I set my base class fields and methods to `private` I don't expose any implementation details to the subclass, right? So changes to to the base class won't affect my subclasses? With regards to public members I don't see any difference to composition. In both cases those are exposed to the subclass (in case of inheritance) or wrapper class (in the case of composition).

Can anyone show me an example, where inheritance leads to higher coupling than composition when the members are set to private/public?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does inheritance increase coupling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187277/does-inheritance-increase-coupling)

Comment: When using inheritance, changes to the superclass (like renaming of the class or its public methods) require updating the subclass and all code that uses it.  With composition, any changes to the depedency affect only the composing class.

Comment: @VGR how is that different to using composition? In that case I would have to change all wrapper classes that act as the subtype as well. (name of base class field or method names)

Comment: Probably.  But not code all over the place in the application.  The “damage” is pretty localized.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't expose any implementation details to the subclass, right?

You are. The fact that your `Dog` class extends `Animal` is *itself* exposing an implementation detail.

Imagine the following 2 very similar takes on the same idea: A class representing a dog kennel.

### Take 1 - composition

```
class Kennel implements Iterable<Dog> {
  private final List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

  public int size() { return dogs.size(); }
  public void addDog(Dog dog) { dogs.add(dog); }
  @Override public Iterator<Dog> iterator() { return dogs.iterator(); }
}
```

### Take 2 - inheritance

```
class Kennel extends ArrayList<Dog> {}
```

Yes, one advantage of take 2 is that it's way less code. But, take 2 relinquishes a lot of control over your API to the authors of ArrayList, and limits any future changes.

For example:

- In take 2, if you later decide to switch to an `ArrayDeque` instead, you cannot actually do that. Some code out there might have written `ArrayList<Dog> x = new Kennel();` and when you make that change, that code would now no longer compile. When you change your API such that it is possible for code to exist that used to work but now no longer compiles / work, that's called a **backwards incompatible change** and you can't release that without upping the major version number, not something you'd want to do likely. In contrast, in take 1, you can just do that. No users of your code would ever know about it.
- In take 2, you get all the methods ArrayList exposes 'for free' and it is indeed vastly less typing. However, you get **all of them** and you do not get to pick and choose. For example, your Kennel class will now also have the `ensureCapacity` method. Even if you ask users of Kennel to disregard the inheritance chain, that method just doesn't make sense except for a very limited set of lists. You've now tightly bound your Kennel class to work like that. For example, if you replace it with LinkedList instead, where `ensureCapacity` fundamentally does not make any sense, you're more or less force to do this:

```
class Kennel extends LinkedList<Dog> { // used to be ArrayList
  public void ensureCapacity(int cap) {
    // do nothing - linkedlists don't work like that
  }
}
```

This is, other than changing the inheritance, 'not breaking anything' - anything that already existed that called `ensureCapacity` (which was a `public` method on your `Kennel` class, after all) continues to work, more or less. But having to add and maintain this do-nothing method that remains for historic reasons is just bizarre.

In contrast, take 1 doesn't suffer from this problem either.

### So what's the lesson?

You may be drawing the conclusion from the above that inheritance is always wrong.

Not so.

The actual lesson is: Inheritance **must make semantic sense**. Remember, if you write `class Foo extends Bar` you're saying: All instances of Foo are also instances of Bar. Just, more specific takes on the idea.

Saying `all Kennels are also ArrayList<Dog> objects` is pushing it. That's not an obvious true thing.

Contrast `class Dog extends Animal`. That's saying: All dogs are also animals; just more specific takes on the idea. Which is trivially true, and is a sensible thing to write.

Moving away from the tired old chestnut of dogs and animals, `class ArrayList extends AbstractList` is effectively the same thing: Yes, all arraylists are abstractlists. Yes, it's okay that this is now hardcoded into the spec of ArrayList for life. It'd be weird if ever it wasn't.

That's perhaps the easiest way to do it: Can you imagine `Kennel` to exist sensibly as **not** being a subclass of `ArrayList<Dog>`? If you can, that very strongly suggests it shouldn't ever be. I cannot imagine `Dog` to exist sensibly as **not** being a subtype of `Animal`. That just doesn't make sense. Dogs **are** animals. That's inherent to the thing you are modeling. It's not an implementation detail - it's a detail of the very concept that this code is merely a software representation for.

To determine if something makes semantic sense, getting into implementation anything is always wrong. It doesn't matter if the thousand-kilometer-overview design of a Kennel so happens to look rather suspiciously similar to `List<Dog>`. All that matters is if the semantic notion of 'the concept "Kennel" inherently screams 'that is a more specific take on the concept "List"'. It just is not. Hence `class Kennel extends ArrayList<Dog>`, while perhaps initially convenient, has no business being in a properly written API.

Comment: Can you exemplify your argument on an inheritance example thatis actually turned into a composition example? In yours the composition example has nothing to do with the inheritance example. How can I do ArrayList<Dog> x = new Kennel() in the composition example?

Comment: @cobby you're mistaken - my 2 snippets _are_ what you're asking for: An inheritance example (`class Kennel extends ArrayList<Dog>`) turned into its equivalent composition example (`class Kennel { private final ArrayList<Dog> = new ArrayList<Dog>(); /* wrapper methods here */ }`). _How can I do ArrayList<Dog> x = new Kennel() in the composition example?_ - __you can't__. That's what composition means.